# how to delete "\" from a text with a condition

Tags: python, string

I have a text that contains "\n" and "\r" to pass to the next line and there is just "\" which I should delete
here is an example of text

```
text="here \n is \r an example\ of a text\ to test"
```

I tried this line

```
text=text.replace("\\","")
```

but it deletes all the "\" while I want to keep only "\n" and "\r"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current string, `\r` and `\n` are a carriage return and a newline, so if you use `text=text.replace("\\","")` it will replace the backslash and the output will be:

```
here 
 an example of a text to test
```

If you want to keep it like that, you can use a raw string starting with `r"` and replace only the `/` when not directly followed by either `r` or `n` using a negative lookahead.

```
import re

text = r"here \n is \r an example\ of a text\ to test"
print(text)
text = re.sub(r"\\(?![rn])", "", text)
print(text)
```

Output

```
here \n is \r an example\ of a text\ to test
here \n is \r an example of a text to test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a lookahead:

```
text = re.sub("\\(?=[^nr]*)", "", text)
```